Maven test fails when run through Github actions but not when run locally
When I run this test locally it passes, however when pushed to GitHub is fails.
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class TestTest {
    String expectedString;
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        expectedString = "woof";
    }


    @Test
    public void testBark() {
        assertEquals(expectedString, "woof");
    }

    @Test
    public void bark(){
        assertEquals(expectedString, "woof");
    }
}

The error message:
Running TestTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.012 sec <<< FAILURE!
TestTest.testBark()  Time elapsed: 0.011 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <null> but was: <woof>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:177)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:1141)
    at TestTest.testBark(TestTest.java:15)
Results :
Failed tests:   TestTest.testBark(): expected: <null> but was: <woof>
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

So clearly @BeforeEach is not being run. When run through github, it only recognises public classes and public methods. It also doesn't run methods that don't have test in their name which I didn't think was necessary with JUnit 5 tests.
My maven.yml file:
name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          java-version: '21'
          distribution: 'temurin'
      - name: Run the Maven verify phase
        run: mvn --batch-mode --update-snapshots verify

My pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.myCustomModule</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.2-beta</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>24.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

I have tried running mvn --batch-mode --update-snapshots verify locally which runs fine and runs all tests. It runs my package private Test classes with package private test methods that don't have test in their name and they all pass. When I then push to github it only runs public classes and methods and only methods with test in their name.

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

I added this to my pom.xml file and everything worked.
